# Loop Animation on several UIButton's NSLayoutConstraint

Tags: objective-c, animation

I took the belated plunge to look at Autolayout.  Normally I'd animate based on a UIView's frame (i.e I'd have used the following):

```
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.buttonArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];

for (int i = 0;i<sortedArray.count;i++) {

    UIButton * theButton = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:i *0.05 usingSpringWithDamping:10 initialSpringVelocity:20 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [theButton setFrame:frameToAnimateTo];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Am I right in thinking that I now have to animate based on the `Constant` property of a buttons `constraint`?

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [self.ButtonHorizonalConstraints sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:ascendingSort]];

for (int i = 0;i<sortedArray.count;i++) {

    NSLayoutConstraint * constraint = [sortedArray objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton * theButton = constraint.firstItem;

    constraint.constant = toShow?0:-theButton.frame.size.width;
    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:i *(toShow?0.1:0.05) usingSpringWithDamping:10 initialSpringVelocity:toShow?20:-20 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
}
```

The end result I get is what I desire, but something doesn't seem right.

Comment: How many elements in your buttons array?

Comment: @sha 10 at present but its dynamic based upon values I get back from some Web API backend

Comment: I don't think you want to call `animateWithDuration` inside the loop. Instead try to call `beginAnimation` before, set all changes in frame in the loop and call `commitAnimation` after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with animating auto-layout constraints.  Fortunately (or unfortunately), I've not yet ever had the need to do this.  So, I'm not sure if there's a better way, but I'd say if it's working, that's a good sign.

What I do want to comment on is your readability:

> ```
> constraint.constant = toShow?0:-theButton.frame.size.width;
> [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
> ```

I don't mind ternary operators.  But I think you really need to include some white space.  When it's all smushed together, and including the negative sign, I had to do a double take before I realized what's going on.

```
constraint.constant = toShow ? 0 : -theButton.frame.size.width;
```

---

> ```
> [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:i *(toShow?0.1:0.05) usingSpringWithDamping:10 initialSpringVelocity:toShow?20:-20
> ```
>
> options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
>           [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
>       } completion:nil];

This method call suffers the same problems as before with the smushed ternary operator, except it's worse because this method has so many more arguments and you're calculating so much in line and you're not using any vertical space.

I'd rewrite this as such:

```
CGFloat animationDelay = i * (toShow ? 0.1 : 0.05);
CGFloat springVelocity = toShow ? 20 : -20;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:animationDelay
     usingSpringWithDamping:10
      initialSpringVelocity:springVelocity
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{

    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];

               } completion:nil];
```

With that spacing, even if we kept the ternaries in-line, it's still significantly more readable with a single argument per line.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to pick back up on that! :)